# In a Joomla component's code, how do I refer to images in a sibling directory?

Tags: jquery, image, joomla, components, assets

I am working on a Joomla component with this basic structure:

```
/components/com_entertainments/assets/js/gameSetup.js
/components/com_entertainments/assets/images/
                                             1.jpg
                                             2.jpg
                                             etc
```

I need to refer to the images from `gameSetup.js`.  I tried several different relative paths,

```
images
../images
/components/com_entertainments/assets/images
./components/com_entertainments/assets/images
./../components/com_entertainments/assets/images
```

but none of them worked.  How do I get at the images from my code?

Comment: You seem to have gotten an answer, but for future reference, when you say something doesn't work, we really need you to be specific about *exactly how* it didn't work.  What errors did you get? What happened instead of the thing you wanted to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to create a javascript var with the base url just before you include your js file, something like this:

```
<?php $baseCompUrl = JURI::root().'components/com_entertainments/'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">var baseCompUrl="<?php echo $baseCompUrl; ?>"</script>
<script src="<?php echo $baseCompUrl; ?>assets/js/gameSetup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now, in `gameSetup.js` file, you can use the variable `baseCompUrl` like this:

```
var imagesPath = baseCompUrl+'assets/images/';
```